# Drag and drop in AUCTeX

Tags: emacs, auctex

I already asked this question on the AUCTeX mailing list via Gmane but can't find the question in the mailing list's archive. Therefore I ask here, too.

Since I'm writing a document with many weird named figures I searched for "auctex drag and drop" and found Michal Sojka's posting: [<878vzs8ppj.fsf@steelpick.2x.cz>](http://www.mail-archive.com/auctex@gnu.org/msg04106.html). Dieter Jurzitza created a patch to tex.el that ["will not work 'out of the box'"](http://www.mail-archive.com/auctex@gnu.org/msg04118.html). I tried to apply the patch to `tex.el`. But it failed. I copied Michal's code to both `tex.el` and later `~/.emacs` and added `(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'auctex-dnd-mode)` to `~/.emacs`; didn't work.

Output of Messages buffer:

---

```
Source file `/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/auctex/tex.el' newer than byte-compiled file

Automatic display of crossref information was turned on Applying style hooks... 

Loading /home/[...] 

Unable to load color "(:line-width 1 :style release-button)" [2 times] 

Loading /home/[...] Loading /usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/auctex/style/graphicx.elc...done 

[...] 

Applying style hooks... done Type C-c C-c to view the image as text.
```

---

What do I need to do to get Michal's code to work? I have no programming skills ...

I use Emacs 23.3.1 on Ubuntu 11.10 with the latest AUCTeX version (11.86).

**[Update:]** With the help of Dieter I solved the problem. He sent me a tex.el with Michal's code that I had to byte-compile in Emacs.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Could you please describe in more detail how you used the code and how it failed.

Comment: I added the code to tex.el, added (add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'auctex-dnd-mode) to ~/.emacs, restartet Emacs and dragged and dropped a JPEG file to a TeX buffer—then the JPEG file was shown in a new buffer, but the .tex-file was not changed.

Comment: Any messages in \*Messages\* when you did that?

Comment: Source file `/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/auctex/tex.el' newer than byte-compiled file

Automatic display of crossref information was turned on
Applying style hooks...

Loading /home/[...]

Unable to load color "(:line-width 1 :style release-button)" [2 times]

Loading /home/[...]

Loading /usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/auctex/style/graphicx.elc...done

[...]

Applying style hooks... done

Type C-c C-c to view the image as text.

Comment: Please edit your question to include new information rather than posting it as comments.

Comment: @typokurz: Welcome from me as well! Glad to see you here, I'm a [big fan of _typokurz_](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26000/4012).

Comment: We'd like to keep answers separate from questions, so you should write a separate answer instead of editing your answer into the question. (BTW, *typokurz* is very nice!)

Answer (score 2):

It is working on my Emacs! Try enabling the minor mode manually:
`M-x auctex-dnd-mode`